# EMQX http ACL auth - broker isn't available

Tags: mqtt, paho

I use EMQ X Broker v4.0.1. Simple http auth is work fine, but when I try to use http ACL auth - it doesn't work for me, despite the fact that settings are very close. When I try to refer to the broker via Eclipse Paho I get the error with status code 3 that means the broker isn't available. I turned on emqx_auth_http from dashboard. This is my EMQX settings for http ACL auth:

**emqx.conf**

```
listener.tcp.external = 1884
plugins/emqx_auth_http.conf

auth.http.auth_req = http://127.0.0.1:8991/mqtt/auth
auth.http.auth_req.method = post
auth.http.auth_req.params = clientid=%c,username=%u,password=%P

auth.http.super_req = http://somesite.com/mqtt/superuser
auth.http.super_req.method = post
auth.http.super_req.params = clientid=%c,username=%u

auth.http.acl_req = http://somesite/mqtt/acl
auth.http.acl_req.method = post
auth.http.acl_req.params = access=%A,username=%u,clientid=%c,ipaddr=%a,topic=%t,mountpoint=%m

auth.http.request.retry_times = 3
auth.http.request.retry_interval = 1s
auth.http.request.retry_backoff = 2.0
```

Endpoints(http://somesite.com/mqtt/superuser, http://somesite/mqtt/acl) are working fine and I can get access to it from Postaman app. May be you could tell me where I do something wrong in my configuration or somewhere else?

Comment: can this be https? or no?

Comment: I can also confirm this, emqx:5.0.25 in docker. Managed to setup HTTP Auth, but Autz not making any requests (despite it being the only one property). No logs , both POST & GET not working, users can connect to any topic :/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe uou need to provide your HTTP server code.

#### http respose status 200 is ok

#### http respose status 4xx is unauthorized

#### http respose status 200 and body is `ignore` means break

This is a project just passed the test:
[egg-iot-with-mqtt](https://github.com/wivwiv/egg-iot-with-mqtt/blob/master/app/controller/home.js#L167)

```js
/**
 * Auth
 */
router.post('/mqtt/auth', async (ctx, next) => {
  const { clientid, username, password } = ctx.request.body
  // Mock
  // 200 means ok
  if (clientid === '' || 'your condition') {
    ctx.body = ''
  } else {
    // 4xx unauthorized
    ctx.status = 401
  }
})

/**
 * ACL
 */
router.post('/mqtt/acl', async (ctx, next) => {
  /**
   * Request Body
   * access:  1 | 2, 1 = sub, 2 = pub
   * access in body now is string !!!
  {
    access: '1',
    username: 'undefined',
    clientid: 'mqttjs_bf980bf7',
    ipaddr: '127.0.0.1',
    topic: 't/1',
    mountpoint: 'undefined'
  }
   */
  const info = ctx.request.body

  console.log(info)

  if (info.topic === 't/2') {
    // 200 is ok
    ctx.body = ''
  } else {
    // 4xx is unauthorized
    ctx.status = 403
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you fro your reply. I think it was broker configure issue. I figured out with this problem but I don't know how. I've reinstalled broker and configure it with same properties and auth is working fine now.